# Bitwise 7 | ~5 = -1; Seriously?

Tags: php, bit-manipulation

I've been trying to figure out bitwise operators again today, and some things are still a little fuzzy to me. Everything made sense until I started trying to combine the | operator with ~, for instance: `number | ~number`. On a side note, I already read the wikipedia article on the two's complement, and understand that aspect of it (I think).

```
------------------------------------------
| 128 | 64 | 32 | 16 |  8 |  4 |  2 |  1 |
------------------------------------------
|   0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  1 |  1 |  1 | = 7
------------------------------------------
|   1 |  1 |  1 |  1 |  1 |  0 |  1 |  0 | = ~5 or -6
------------------------------------------
```

Using the & operator like `7 & ~5` yields the expected result of 2, as only the 2 column is set in both rows. What's getting me here is that `7 | ~5` is outputting -1. I'd expect that would either be 255, because every column has a 1 in it, or 5, because the bottom row might count 0s instead of 1s. But it's neither of those, it's -1.

I've googled this until my brain hurts, and I can't find one single article anywhere that addresses this. Does anyone know what's going on here?

Answer (score 9):

The result of `7 | ~5` is a bit pattern of all ones. That's -1 in two's complement.

Comment: But if you can tap into an unsigned data type, then you may get the answer you're expecting.

Comment: @Richard - True, except for the inconvenient fact that [php does not support unsigned integers](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php).

Comment: OF COURSE! I should have seen that before! Thank you very very much. This has been driving me insane for a really long time.

Comment: @ScottyC., the key point is that when the uppermost bit is set the number is interpreted as negative.